# Trigger on PostGIS line layer occurs twice

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, trigger

Using [this](http://twiav-tt.blogspot.com/2013/04/postgis-trigger-function-keeping-track.html) tutorial, I've established a SQL trigger in order to track changes on a PostGIS layer. It works great for a point layer. However, using the script below, it causes problems with line layer, as all of the triggers occur twice.

I first realized this because the history table inserts lines for the 'INSERT' and `UPDATE` logic twice (not for `DELETE`, surprisingly). The notices print to the console twice for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`.

For example:

- When creating a line in the base table, the history table creates two objects with the same attributes except for the hid (history table id).
- When updating the attribute of an existing line, in the history table, three objects are created:

  1. One with `etat = 'MODIFICATION COURANTE'` (resembles the existing feature in the base table, including the updated attribute)
  2. Two with `etat = 'MODIFICATION ARCHIVEE'` -- one with the old attribute value and one with the new attribute value. At this point, I am expecting only one object containing the old attribute. The object containing the new attribute is out if place.

```sql
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION test.test_track_history_tracker() RETURNS trigger AS
$new_test_track_history_tracker$
BEGIN
  -- INSERT

  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
     INSERT INTO test."Conduite_test_history"
        (diametre, type, materiau, origininfo, dtreno, dtpose, reparateur, dt_dmd, id_sig, gid_org, created, created_by, modified, etat, geom)
     VALUES
         (NEW.diametre, NEW.type, NEW.materiau, NEW.origininfo, NEW.dtreno, NEW.dtpose, NEW.reparateur, NEW.dt_dmd, NEW.id_sig, NEW.gid, current_timestamp,
         current_user, FALSE, 'CREATION', NEW.geom);
     raise notice 'Insert happened';
     RETURN NEW;

  -- UPDATE
  ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
     UPDATE test."Conduite_test_history"
         SET deleted = current_timestamp, deleted_by = current_user, modified = TRUE, etat = 'MODIFICATION ARCHIVEE'
     WHERE deleted IS NULL and gid_org = OLD.gid;

     INSERT INTO test."Conduite_test_history"
         (diametre, type, materiau, origininfo, dtreno, dtpose, reparateur, dt_dmd, id_sig, gid_org, created, created_by, modified, etat, geom)
     VALUES
         (NEW.diametre, NEW.type, NEW.materiau, NEW.origininfo, NEW.dtreno, NEW.dtpose, NEW.reparateur, NEW.dt_dmd, NEW.id_sig, NEW.gid, current_timestamp,
         current_user, FALSE, 'MODIFICATION COURANTE', NEW.geom);
     raise notice 'Update happened';
     RETURN NEW;
  -- DELETE
  ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
     UPDATE test."Conduite_test_history"
       SET deleted = current_timestamp, 
           deleted_by = current_user, 
           etat = 'SUPPRESSION'
     WHERE deleted is NULL and gid_org = OLD.gid;
     raise notice 'Delete happened';
     RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
END;
$new_test_track_history_tracker$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

--ADD TRIGGER
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_test_track_history_tracker ON test."Conduite_test";
CREATE TRIGGER trg_test_track_history_tracker 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON test."Conduite_test"
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.test_track_history_tracker();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an AFTER trigger - thus any action will have already taken place and the UPDATE will actually run twice: once the for the "original" statement and then again from within your trigger.

It seems to be, you actually want a BEFORE trigger. And there you just assign values to the NEW row, rather than UPDATEing the table itself.

So I *think* what you are looking for is something like this:

```sql
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION test.test_track_history_tracker() 
  RETURNS trigger AS
$new_test_track_history_tracker$
BEGIN
  -- INSERT

  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
     INSERT INTO test."Conduite_test_history"
        (diametre, type, materiau, origininfo, dtreno, dtpose, reparateur, dt_dmd, id_sig, gid_org, created, created_by, modified, etat, geom)
     VALUES
         (NEW.diametre, NEW.type, NEW.materiau, NEW.origininfo, NEW.dtreno, NEW.dtpose, NEW.reparateur, NEW.dt_dmd, NEW.id_sig, NEW.gid, current_timestamp,
         current_user, FALSE, 'CREATION', NEW.geom);
     raise notice 'Insert happened';

     -- continue with the INSERT
     RETURN NEW;

  -- UPDATE
  ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
     -- this IF is equivalent to your WHERE statement 
     IF new.deleted IS NULL THEN 
       new.deleted := current_timestamp;
       new.deleted_by := current_user;
       new.modified := true; 
       new.eta := 'MODIFICATION ARCHIVEE';
     END IF;

     INSERT INTO test."Conduite_test_history"
         (diametre, type, materiau, origininfo, dtreno, dtpose, reparateur, dt_dmd, id_sig, gid_org, created, created_by, modified, etat, geom)
     VALUES
         (NEW.diametre, NEW.type, NEW.materiau, NEW.origininfo, NEW.dtreno, NEW.dtpose, NEW.reparateur, NEW.dt_dmd, NEW.id_sig, NEW.gid, current_timestamp,
         current_user, FALSE, 'MODIFICATION COURANTE', NEW.geom);
     raise notice 'Update happened';

     RETURN NEW; -- continue with the UPDATE
  -- DELETE
  ELSEIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN

     -- this is correct: it will turn the DELETE into an UPDATE
     UPDATE test."Conduite_test_history"
        SET deleted = current_timestamp, deleted_by = current_user, etat = 'SUPPRESSION'
     WHERE deleted is NULL and gid_org = OLD.gid;
     raise notice 'Delete happened';

     RETURN NULL; -- this will prevent the actual DELETE in t
  END IF;
END;
$new_test_track_history_tracker$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then create a `BEFORE` trigger using that trigger function:

```
--ADD TRIGGER
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_test_track_history_tracker ON test."Conduite_test";
CREATE TRIGGER trg_test_track_history_tracker 
  BEFORE 
       INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON test."Conduite_test"
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test.test_track_history_tracker();
```